# replace several values at once in a dict in tcl

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I have a dict with several elements. I want to replace several values at once.

This is how it has worked:

```
 proc  myproc  {param} {


      set tempDict [dict replace $param "fd" "gfdgfdgf"]
      set tempDict2 [dict replace $tempDict "fds" "gfdgf"]
      set tempDict3 [dict replace $tempDict2 "fsdf" "gdfg7"]
      set tempDict4 [dict replace $tempDict3 "ztrzrt" "gdfgf"]

      puts "\n"
      puts $tempDict4

  }
```

What's the right way to do this? The way I understand the documentation, `dict replace` returns a copy of the altered dict. But my code surely cannot be the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can append more than one key/value pair.

```
% set d [ dict create user dinesh age 25 ]
user dinesh age 25
% set d [dict replace $d user Rajesh age 29]
user Rajesh age 29
%
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `dict merge` command. The values of the last specified dictionary will take precedence:

```
% dict merge {a 1 b 2} {a 11 c 33}
a 11 b 2 c 33
```